# How can i get current Unix timestamp utc time in the android project (internet time)

Tags: android, unix-timestamp

I am building an android project in which i needed to store Unix timestamps in firebase but i am not able to find a way to get the unix timestamps into my project to get current unix timestamp (internet time, not the system time)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
String unixTimeStamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "";
```

Comment: Try this Long unixtime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;